# Validating fields in a RAML datatype against each other

Tags: mule, raml

I need to create a RAML datatype for a request where a user can enter the First Name and Last Name or Business Name. If the user is entering the First Name, then he should give the Last name also, but not the Business Name. This is the datatype I created in which I made all these three fields as not required. This is also the structure of the JSON request I am expecting.

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
properties:
  account_number:
    type: string
    required: true
  first_name:
    type: string
    required: false
  last_name:
    type: string
    required: false
  business_name:
    type: string
    required: false
```

This won't make any sense to my use case. So I tried defining the First Name and Last Name as a different type by making them required and link it to the parent by making the linked field as not required.

userType.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
properties:
  account_number:
    type: string
    required: true
  name: 
    type: !include nameType.raml
    required: false
  business_name:
    type: string
    required: false
```

nameType.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
properties:
  first_name:
    type: string
    required: true
  last_name:
    type: string
    required: true
```

This seems not working when I mock the request. My question is:

1. Can we do this kind of validation in RAML?
2. If yes, how can I define the datatype so that I fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in [Union](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#union-type) types.

This definition will have the disired behavior:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: union types

types:
  person_name:
    type: object
    properties:
      first_name:
      last_name:
  business_name:
    type: string
  entity_name: person_name | business_name


/entity:
  get:
    queryString:
      type: entity_name
```

Now I did try MuleSoft's Mocking Service which is what I think you refer to by "mocking".  It seems the mocking service cannot handle union types.  This is not an issue of RAML but of the Mocking Service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can we do this kind of validation in RAML? - **YES**
2. How can I define the datatype so that I fulfill my requirement?

The answer to your question 2nd question is below (but it will not work on the Design Centre(Mulesoft), as there is a Bug. But will work on the locally deployed API and even on the cloud-hub of Mulesoft after deployment)

**define the DataType as below** (I created some folder and inside it files to make more feasible and readable, but you can adjust it)

1. created folder **inside API folder types -> request ->** then file called **nameType.raml** and **userType.raml** and it has below content

- nameType.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  first_name:
    type: string
  last_name:
    type: string
```

- userType.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
description: user type

type: object
properties:
  business_name:
    type: string
    required: true
```

- create a **libraries** folder now and inside that create a **library.raml** file that will have content as below
- library.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

types:
  name: !include ../types/request/nameType.raml
  user: !include ../types/request/userType.raml
```

3. Use all above-defined DataTypes and library.raml in Mail RAML as below

```
#%RAML 1.0
version: v1
title: Test API


uses:
  lb-api: libraries/library.raml


/entity:
  post:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: object
        properties:
          accountNumber:  
            type: string
          name: lb-api.name | lb-api.user
        examples:  {}
    responses:
     
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: 
      400:
        body:
          application/json:
            example:
              {"message": "Search query too long"}
```

above RAML will accept 2 types of request

first Request

```
{
       "accountNumber":"",
       "name":{"business_name": ""}
}
```

second request :

```
{
       "accountNumber":"",
       "name":{
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": ""
            }
}
```

ScreenShot of folder structure

[image]